# GHC-api and typechecking class constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I am trying to build a simple ghci-like console using ghc-api. I've gotten to a point where I can extract `Type`'s of expressions using `exprType` and to evaluate them. Is there also an easy way to check if the type of the expression has an instance of a given class?

Edit: It seems that functions I'm looking for would require an `InstEnv`, but I have no clue where to find that.

Answer (score 3):

The `isInstance` method may do what you require.

Example in ghci:

```
> :set -XTemplateHaskell
> import Language.Haskell.TH
> $(stringE . show =<< (isInstance ''Functor . (: []) =<< [t| [] |]))
"True"
> $(stringE . show =<< (isInstance ''Show . (: []) =<< [t| Maybe Int |]))
"True"
$(stringE . show =<< (isInstance ''Show . (: []) =<< [t| (Int -> Bool) |]))
"False"
```

Its type sig is

```
isInstance :: Name -> [Type] -> Q Bool
```

Ie you give a name (retrieved using `''` or with the `mkName` function) for the class, then you pass the types to check against the class (more than one will be required if the class is a multiparam type class). It will then return True or False in the Q monad.

Comment: That's promising, but I can't also think of a way to run Q monad within the GHC monad.